# Django: How to put existing fields when displaying form for UpdateView?

Tags: python, django

I'm making an episode tracker website and when I want the user to edit a show, the form provided starts with empty fields. How do I fill the form with already existing fields? For example, when a user is watching a show and is originally at episode 5, how do I call the update form with the Episode field already at 5 instead of it being empty?

**views.py**

```
class ShowUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Show
    slug_field = 'title'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'show'
    fields = ['description', 'season', 'episode']
```

**show-detail.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'show:show-update' show=show.title %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You haven't included the actual `{{ form }}` in your template. Also, UpdateView expects to find the template at '/appname/modelname_update.html' so if you're using a different name for your template you should set template_name explicitly  .

Answer (score 1):

You can fill a form with the values in an UpdateView with

```
def get_initial(self):
    return { 'field1': 'something', 'field2': 'more stuff' }
```

Also the UpdateView inherits from the SingleObjectMixin, which provides `get_object` and `get_queryset`, so you could use either to get the object data you want to populate the form with. Something like:

```
def get_object(self):
        return Show.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('pk'))
```

[Check out the docs for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object)

Also, if you have a pk or slug as a parameter in your url, it should pick it up as well. Such as:

```
url(r'^shows/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',ShowUpdate.as_view())
```

Comment: How would I get the values of the instance? {'field1' : 'what_to_put_here'}

Comment: I updated my answer  - hope that helps. You just need to provide the class the object you want to update by either manually setting the field values with get_initial, or getting the object you want to update with get_object.